# Can a dictionary key have multiple values?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I'm trying to organize my data in a way where it looks like this:

```
    { 'Month' = [
         'Day1' : 8
         'Day2' : 6
         'Day3' : 9
         'Day4' : 1
         'Day5' : 2
       ]
    }
```

In a way, I'm trying to have it be a dictionary where the months are the keys and the days are the values for the month. For the sake of this example, we're going to pretend that the numbers listed above for each day represents how many photos I've taken in my camera for that day.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, dictionary values can be collections too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, like so:

```
    { 'Month': {
         'Day1': 8,
         'Day2': 6,
         'Day3': 9,
         'Day4': 1,
         'Day5': 2
       }
    }
```

The value of a dict key can be any type of [collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: thank you! currently trying out this solution and the other solution provided as well. trying to see which one works best for the current script i'm writing. i wish i could accept both answers

Comment: @rand03 this is literally the same exact code I wrote (except for those PEP8 violations), but You can still upvote this answer if You wish to and this answer probably explains better (provides a link) about what dictionary values can be

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```py
{'Month': {
     'Day1': 8,
     'Day2': 6,
     'Day3': 9,
     'Day4': 1,
     'Day5': 2
    }
}
```

just nest dictionaries (also there is no space between key and colon but there is space between value and colon, it is a PEP8 violation: `PEP 8: E203 whitespace before ':'` and `PEP 8: E231 missing whitespace after ':'` and this too `PEP 8: E201 whitespace after '{'`)

Comment: ah, thank you!! i appreciate it. so if let's say i was iterating through this and wanted to append this info, would i just write 'month = day = #_of_pics' ? i know that's not the best way to write it, but i hope that makes sense

Comment: for example if You wanted to increase the number You could do sth like `dct['Month']['Day1'] += 1` or say it was a list then: `dct['Month']['Day1'].append(sth)` where dct is the variable that stores this dictionary, if You wanted to add another day then: `dct['Month']['New_day'] = value` since You are adding a dictionary key, more info about dictionaries can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)